# Why does readline() not work after readlines()?

Tags: python, file, readline, readlines

In Python, say I have:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
    a = f.readlines()
    b = f.readline()
    print a
    print b
```

`print a` will show all the lines of the file and `print b` will show nothing.

Similarly vice versa:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
    a = f.readline()
    b = f.readlines()
    print a
    print b
```

`print a` shows the first line but `print b` will show all lines except the first one.

If both `a` and `b` are readlines(), `a` will show all the lines and `b` will show nothing.

Why does this happen? Why can't both commands work independently of each other? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Readlines reads all of the lines, so there is nothing left to read unless you seek back to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 5):

Because doing `.readlines()` first will consume all of the read buffer leaving nothing behind for `.readline()` to fetch from. If you want to go back to the start, use `.seek(0)` as @abccd already mentioned in his answer.

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> buffer = StringIO('''hi there
... next line
... another line
... 4th line''')
>>> buffer.readline()
'hi there\n'
>>> buffer.readlines()
['next line\n', 'another line\n', '4th line']
>>> buffer.seek(0)
>>> buffer.readlines()
['hi there\n', 'next line\n', 'another line\n', '4th line']
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `readlines` read all the lines in the file, so there's no more lines left to read, to read the file again, you can use `f.seek(0)` to go back to the beginning and read from there.

Answer (score 1):

Files have a byte offset which is updated whenever you read or write them. This will do what you initially expected:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    a = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)  # seek to the beginning of the file
    b = f.readline()
```

Now `a` is all the lines and `b` is just the first line.